# jQuery - Assignment to constant variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The problem is that one of the statements will be false, the variable doesn't want "(let usernameError)" to work, but if I overwrite it with "const", the script will work, but it will print an error.

**Error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

I know I’m writing about a very easy problem, but I can’t figure out what the solution might be.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="target" class="signin-form" method="post">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username.." name="username" id="usernames" maxlength="15" required>

  <div class="error">
     <p id="usercheck">Username must be at least 6 characters long.</p>
  </div>

  <input type="button" id="submitbtn" value="Register" class="registerbtn">
</form
```

**jQuery:**

```
// Document is ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    
// Validate Username
    $('#usercheck').hide();
    const usernameError = true;
    $('#usernames').keyup(function () {
        validateUsername();
    });

    function validateUsername() {
        let usernameValue = $('#usernames').val();

        if (usernameValue.length == '') {
        $('#usercheck').show();
            usernameError = false;
            return false;

        } else if ((usernameValue.length < 6)||(usernameValue.length > 15)) {
        $('#usercheck').show();
            usernameError = false;
            return false;

        } else {
            $('#usercheck').hide();
        }
    }
     
// Submit button
    $('#submitbtn').click(function () {
        validateUsername();

        if ((usernameError == true)) {
            $( "#target" ).submit();
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

I tried with all possible variables, for example: var, let, const...

Comment: `const usernameError = true;` is a `const`.  It would need to be `let`, but you have a logic problem where `usernameError` will never be set back to true.

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't want "(let usernameError)" to work`?
Anyway, `const` can't be re-assigned, so you won't be able to use `usernameError = false`.

Comment: Look up the differences between `const`, `let` and `var`.

Comment: Also, if you used `let usernameError = true` instead, once you run into `usernameError = false`, you don't have anything to change it back to `true`. "Once false, always false". Maybe you should add `usernameError = true;` before `$('#usercheck').hide();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolve error:**

```
let usernameError = true;
```

**Solving a logical problem:**

```
function validateUsername() {
    let usernameValue = $('#usernames').val();

    if (usernameValue.length == '') {
    $('#usercheck').show();
        usernameError = false;
        return false;

    } else if ((usernameValue.length < 6)||(usernameValue.length > 15)) {
    $('#usercheck').show();
        usernameError = false;
        return false;

    } else {
        $('#usercheck').hide();
        usernameError = true;
    }
}
```

If the input changes to false, it prints the error, but after correcting the error, it does not overwrite the variable, only the display was overwritten.

```
$('#usercheck').hide();
usernameError = true;
```